# pytest : How to write pytest code to detect a "func" called without actually executing the "func"

Tags: python, pytest

pytest : How to write pytest code to detect a "func" called without actually executing the "func" ,

target.py:

```
import requests
import threading

CFG=None
targets={}

def add_target(func):
    targets[func.__name__] = func
    return func


def parent_func(url):
    for funct in set(targets):
        threading.Thread(target=targets[funct], args=(CFG[url],)).start()

@add_target
def child_func(url):
    try:
        response = requests.request("POST", url,
                                    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                                    data="{\"text\": \"target py test\"}")
        response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as err:
        raise RuntimeError(err)
```

test_target.py:

During testing, I want child_func() to get called but the child_func() body should not get executed. Rather, after running tests, child_func() gets executed & test run results in "AssertionError: False is not true "

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
import target

# Third-party imports...
from nose.tools import assert_true, assert_is_not_none
target.CFG={'url':"some valid url"}
@patch('target.child_func')
def test_child_func(mock_child_func):
    parent_func("url")
    assert_true(mock_child_func.called)
```

Comment: You patched `child_func`, not `target_func`, so the real `target_func` (whatever it is) got called when you called `parent_func`.

Comment: I added the missing imports according to my best guesses and the test passes just fine.  Since you edited the typo in your original post, you might want to double-check for typos in your actual code as well; if the test still fails, please post the files for your MRE in their entirety (including dependencies, imports, etc).

Comment: @Samwise  Please see the updated target.py. Now, you should get "AssertionError: False is not true". Please let me know. I don't know how to get around this

Comment: Next time please try to run your example *before* posting it.  :)  The actual source of the problem was something that was entirely missing from your original question!

Answer (score 1):

First (for the sake of my own sanity) let's whittle this down to an actual MRE -- we don't actually need `threading` or `requests` or any of the implementation details of `child_func` to demonstrate the problem here.

target.py:

```
targets={}

def add_target(func):
    targets[func.__name__] = func
    return func

def parent_func(url):
    for func in targets.values():
        func(url)

@add_target
def child_func(url):
    raise NotImplementedError("The test shouldn't actually call this function!")
```

test_target.py:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from target import parent_func

@patch('target.child_func')
def test_parent_func(mock_child_func):
    parent_func("url")
    assert mock_child_func.call_count == 1
```

Within our test, we want `parent_func` to call `mock_child_func`, not the real `child_func`.  But when we run our test, we can quickly see that our patch didn't work:

```
============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
FAILED test_target.py::test_parent_func - NotImplementedError: The test shouldn't actually call this function!
```

The reason for this is that **`parent_func` doesn't call `child_func`, it calls `targets['child_func']`**.  Patching `'target.child_func'` doesn't modify the actual *function*, it modifies what the *name* `child_func` points to in the `target` module -- and that name isn't in use in the code under test!

The easiest fix here is to patch `target.targets`:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from target import parent_func

@patch('target.targets', new_callable=dict)
def test_parent_func(mock_targets):
    mock_targets['child_func'] = Mock()
    parent_func("url")
    assert mock_targets['child_func'].call_count == 1
```

Now our test passes because when `parent_func` iterates through its `targets`, it gets our `mock_targets` dict, which we can populate with whatever functions/mocks we want.

Comment: Thanks & I get this. But my intention is to test whether or not                                          parent_func() in target.py  --calls--> child_func() in target.py via this test code. Of course, it gets tricky with decorators, not sure whether the mock_targets satisfy that. Is it possible to simulate the "@add_target child_func() " part in the test code , and then call parent_func() from the same test code.

Comment: I'd suggest that you independently test: (1) is `child_func` (the real one) in the real `targets` dict?  (2) does `parent_func` call every function in `targets`?  (The above test is mostly about (2).)  These are both easy to test individually by mocking different pieces in different test functions.  If you want to test it all together, then you need to mock out `requests` and any other dependencies of `child_func` so you can have the *real* `parent_func` call the *real* `child_func`.

Comment: The other option would be to monkey-patch the *real* `target.targets` in your test, but that feels bad to me (it has a strong likelihood of "leaking" and screwing up other tests in the same suite) and I don't think it makes the test any better.